# Trouble downloading updates due to 404 error "Failed to fetch"

Tags: 14.04

I have got trouble downloading updates due to 404 error

```
Failed to fetch
W: Failed to fetch http://vn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your mirror of repository.

To change your mirror follow this article in [www.allfreeubuntu.tk](http://www.allfreeubuntu.tk/configure/)